# Content Wont Align Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I need some help with my page, the content isn't aligning properly to the content of webpage and I have no idea how to proceed. It is supposed to have a margin on the left so it does not touch the sidebar, as well as the footer being on the bottom. I will upload an image of what my page looks like atm. Any help is appreciated.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  display: block;
}

 /* SCROLL BAR CSS STARTS */
body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 0.30rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
  background: #212429;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { 
  background:#fc3218 ;
}
/* SCROLL BAR CSS ENDS */


.lateral-nav {
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;background:#fafafc;height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:flex-start;align-items:center; 
    }
      img {
      width:60px;height:45px;margin-top:5px;
    }

    .lateral-nav a {
        writing-mode:vertical-lr;text-orientation:mixed;margin:10px 0;}


    .navbar {
      margin-top:10px;

    }

    /* NAV BAR CSS STARTS */
    .my-nav{
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 15px;
      }

    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: white;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li {
        padding-left:35px;
        padding-right:55px;
        float:none;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
      color: #fc3218;
    }

    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:active { 
      color: #fc3218;
    }


    .navbar {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      background: #22252a;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      color: white;
      background-color: #fc3218;
  }

  .dropdown-item { 
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
    /* NAV BAR CSS END */

/* SIDE BAR CSS STARTS */
  .socialbox { 
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    margin: -120px 0 0;
    text-align: center;

  }
  .socialbox img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.socialbox::before {
  content: "#Suivez-nous";
  bottom: -180px;
  left: -38px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #000f33;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.socialbox::after {
  content: "";
  bottom: -110px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2px;
  background-color: #dddee4;
}

.socialbox::after, .socialbox::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.socialbox .fa {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000f33;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}
/* SIDE BAR CSS ENDS */

/* Footer start */

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background: #16222A;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A);
  background: linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A);
  color: white;
  margin-top:10px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 92.99%;
clear: both;



}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #FA944B;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.footer-middle {
  padding-top: 2em;

  color: white;
}


/*SOCİAL İCONS*/

/* footer social icons */

ul.social-network {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.social-network li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px;
}


/* footer social icons */

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007bb7;
}

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i,
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.social-network a.socialIcon:hover,
.socialHoverClass {
  color: #44BCDD;
}

.social-circle li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.social-circle li i {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-circle li a:hover i,
.triggeredHover {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms--transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.social-circle i {
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.social-network a {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

/* Footer end */
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/">

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
        <nav class="my-nav navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
           target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
           label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample08">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown08" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
                     haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACTIVITES</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown08">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rafting</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Canooing</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Parachute</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Soufflerie</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Saut elastique</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>

                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">OFFRES</a>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">EVENEMENTS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">A PROPOS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ESPACE HANDICAP</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>


  <div class="lateral-nav">
                <a href="#"><img src="./img/so.png" alt=""></a>
                <div class="socialbox ">
    <a href="#"><img class="fa fa-facebook" src="./img/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="fa fa-twitter" src="./img/twitter.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="fa fa-youtube" src="./img/youtube.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</div>

<main>
  <h2 class="text-center">NOS ACTIVITES</h2>
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body rafting">
      <h5 class="card-title">RAFTING</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; height: 15rem;">
    <div class="card-body canooing">
      <h5 class="card-title">CANNOING</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body parachute">
      <h5 class="card-title">PARACHUTE</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body soufflerie">
      <h5 class="card-title">SOUFFLERIE</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body saut-elastique">
      <h5 class="card-title">SAUT ELASTIQUE</h5>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


<!-- Footer Start -->
<footer class="mainfooter" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="footer-middle">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <!--Column1-->
        <div class="footer-pad">
          <h4>Heading 1</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Payment Center</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Directory</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News and Updates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <!--Column1-->
        <div class="footer-pad">
          <h4>Heading 2</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Website Tutorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Webmaster</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <!--Column1-->
        <div class="footer-pad">
          <h4>Heading 3</h4>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li><a href="#">Parks and Recreation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Public Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Police Department</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fire</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mayor and City Council</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>Follow Us</h4>
            <ul class="social-network social-circle">
             <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
             <li><a href="#" class="icoLinkedin" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>               
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 copy">
      <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright 2018 - Company Name.  All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
  </div>


  </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</div>
<!-- Footer Ends -->

   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are havving an `li`closed wrong in your `nav`. Correct that

Comment: Actualy you are planty of element not closed as well, `header`, `main` for example.

Comment: Do you see any  `</header>` or `</main>` ?? html is not suppose to know when you are closing them. In nav, your `ul`finish like: `</li>
                  </li>
                </ul>` I guess not correctly closed from your first `li`

Comment: Yes i seem to have missed it at the first look. I have fixed those issues they are all with closing tags now. However not sure what to do with the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment you needed to correct some missing element so I tried to made that first.

If on the below snippet there is a scroll bar horizontal it is because on your css, you are setting `padding: 0` to body, if you set `padding: 8px` It will be fine here

Then I was adding the CSS below (totaly at the bottom of the css):

```
 body{
  max-width: calc(100vw - 19px);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#container{
  width:100%;
}
header, main{
  max-width:100%;
}
nav{
  max-width: calc(100% + 5px);
  width: calc(100% + 5px) !important; /**** Important needed to over<rite bootstrap class ***/
}
main{
  margin-left: 100px;
}
footer{
 width: calc(100% - 85px);
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right: -15px;
```

}

Then I took the footer out of the `div id="container"` to and added the class`footer`on the footer.

### DEMO (try it full screen)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  display: block;
}

 /* SCROLL BAR CSS STARTS */
body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  width: 0.30rem;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
  background: #212429;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { 
  background:#fc3218 ;
}
/* SCROLL BAR CSS ENDS */


.lateral-nav {
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;background:#fafafc;height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:flex-start;align-items:center; 
    }
      img {
      width:60px;height:45px;margin-top:5px;
    }

    .lateral-nav a {
        writing-mode:vertical-lr;text-orientation:mixed;margin:10px 0;}


    .navbar {
      margin-top:10px;

    }

    /* NAV BAR CSS STARTS */
    .my-nav{
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      padding: 15px;
      }

    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: white;
    }

    .navbar-nav > li {
        padding-left:35px;
        padding-right:55px;
        float:none;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
      color: #fc3218;
    }

    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:active { 
      color: #fc3218;
    }


    .navbar {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      background: #22252a;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      color: white;
      background-color: #fc3218;
  }

  .dropdown-item { 
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
    /* NAV BAR CSS END */

/* SIDE BAR CSS STARTS */
  .socialbox { 
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    margin: -120px 0 0;
    text-align: center;

  }
  .socialbox img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.socialbox::before {
  content: "#Suivez-nous";
  bottom: -180px;
  left: -38px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #000f33;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.socialbox::after {
  content: "";
  bottom: -110px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -2px;
  background-color: #dddee4;
}

.socialbox::after, .socialbox::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.socialbox .fa {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000f33;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}
/* SIDE BAR CSS ENDS */

/* Footer start */

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background: #16222A;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A);
  background: linear-gradient(59deg, #3A6073, #16222A);
  color: white;
  margin-top:10px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 92.99%;
clear: both;



}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #FA944B;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.copy {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.footer-middle {
  padding-top: 2em;

  color: white;
}


/*SOCİAL İCONS*/

/* footer social icons */

ul.social-network {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.social-network li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 5px;
}


/* footer social icons */

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover {
  background-color: #3B5998;
}

.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007bb7;
}

.social-network a.icoFacebook:hover i,
.social-network a.icoLinkedin:hover i {
  color: #fff;
}

.social-network a.socialIcon:hover,
.socialHoverClass {
  color: #44BCDD;
}

.social-circle li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.social-circle li i {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-circle li a:hover i,
.triggeredHover {
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms--transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.social-circle i {
  color: #595959;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}

.social-network a {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

/* Footer end */
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}




/***********************************************ADDED***********************/
body{
  max-width: calc(100vw - 19px);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#container{
  width:100%;
}
header, main{
  max-width:100%;
}
nav{
  max-width: calc(100% + 5px);
  width: calc(100% + 5px) !important; /**** Important needed to over<rite bootstrap class ***/
}
main{
  margin-left: 100px;
}
footer{
  width: calc(100% - 85px);
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-+4zCK9k+qNFUR5X+cKL9EIR+ZOhtIloNl9GIKS57V1MyNsYpYcUrUeQc9vNfzsWfV28IaLL3i96P9sdNyeRssA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/">

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
      </head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <nav class="my-nav navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
         target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
         label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample08">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown08" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
               haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACTIVITES</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown08">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rafting</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Canooing</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Parachute</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Soufflerie</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Saut elastique</a>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">OFFRES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">EVENEMENTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">A PROPOS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ESPACE HANDICAP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>


  <div class="lateral-nav">
    <a href="#"><img src="./img/so.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="socialbox ">
      <a href="#"><img class="fa fa-facebook" src="./img/facebook.png" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#"><img class="fa fa-twitter" src="./img/twitter.png" alt=""></a>
      <a href="#"><img class="fa fa-youtube" src="./img/youtube.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <main>
    <h2 class="text-center">NOS ACTIVITES</h2>
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body rafting">
          <h5 class="card-title">RAFTING</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem; height: 15rem;">
        <div class="card-body canooing">
          <h5 class="card-title">CANNOING</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body parachute">
          <h5 class="card-title">PARACHUTE</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body soufflerie">
          <h5 class="card-title">SOUFFLERIE</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body saut-elastique">
          <h5 class="card-title">SAUT ELASTIQUE</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">RÉSERVEZ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>


  
</div>
<!-- Footer Start -->
  <footer class="mainfooter" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="footer-middle">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--Column1-->
            <div class="footer-pad">
              <h4>Heading 1</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Payment Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Directory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Forms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News and Updates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--Column1-->
            <div class="footer-pad">
              <h4>Heading 2</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#">Website Tutorial</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Disclaimer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Webmaster</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <!--Column1-->
            <div class="footer-pad">
              <h4>Heading 3</h4>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#">Parks and Recreation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Public Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Police Department</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fire</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mayor and City Council</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"></a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <h4>Follow Us</h4>
              <ul class="social-network social-circle">
               <li><a href="#" class="icoFacebook" title="Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="icoLinkedin" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
              </ul>               
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 copy">
            <p class="text-center">&copy; Copyright 2018 - Company Name.  All rights reserved.</p>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Footer Ends -->
   <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so yes now the positioning has worked. But something is creating a margin on the top and the sides of my webpage. As well as my side bar not being display in 100vh. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: Are you having a scroll bar horizontal ?

Comment: No, when i changed the padding to 8px to body, like you said and that fixed it. But now I have like a small 5px space between all the corners of my content. I will upload a picture to the post for you to see.

Comment: Try to add on body `max-width: calc(100vw - 19px); min-height: 100vh;` without padding:8px As I did in my post edited

Comment: Thank you!That has fixed the little space on the top portion of the website. However the bottom right of the footer still has a little space and is leaving a gap on the screen. I inspected the page and that little line says its the html element.

Comment: @Simasan I fixed footer to the right by adding: `footer{
      margin-right: -15px;
    }` checking for navbar now

Comment: I have checked the footer, it just pulls it more to the right side and creates an equal space on the left now. Is there some way to actually stretch the footer so its evenly spaced between my side bar and my screen?

Comment: @Simasan Ok so navbar corrected, and I corrected the gap on the footer that was created by increase width of footer by +15px, please check code now. And yes for your footer the easiest would be to set width 100% and margin-left:100px; (edited to make this way)

Comment: @Simasan still any problem?

Comment: Yes so I managed to use the code that you have posted. I still have a few problems with my page. I still have the horizontal bar, however there are no spaces so its a little strange. And for the rest of my content with the cards, they still dont arrange properly and keep crawling up my nav bar. :\ not sure why this is so  problematic to deal with. It does not look at all like your snippet result and idk why since its the same code used.

Comment: Try to make a codepen or an example where I can try to help you. But try to change the `15px` I was adding in footer or navbar to see if it solve problem by you

Comment: Hey MaxiGui, sorry i had my classes over the weekend and was not free. Here I have made a Codepen for the code. I tried working on it however i didn't manage to really advance and all my content is still misaligned. However on Codepen It shows the ''Nos Activites"and it does not on my native screen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/george-simak/pen/BazNOba Here is the link.

Comment: I am not sure if what is happening could be a result of me not writing the code properly and not having made a responsive layout before starting to make the content for the site. Or could it be bootstrap?

Comment: I dont know but as you said, even your codepen seems to work fine so for me there is no more I can do here... I guess your question is solved George as it was: "Content Wont Align Bootstrap". Even If I would love to help you further I cannot because codepen works as it should. So problem solved for me.

Comment: Do you have any idea if this is my computer's fault or could this be something else? Because even in codepen the horizontal scroll bar appears when i click on any content.

Comment: The only way I see the scroll horizontal scroll bar coming is when the button 'réservez' (that should be written 'Réserver') they are coming out of the container. Because their size or the font-size is not dynamic so you should reduice the size or adjust your breakpoint. Otherwise, no matter where I click all seems to be fine

Comment: Alright, I will try to change it that way. Thank you for all the help. Just wanted to find out one last thing. Were the problems that I was facing caused by my low quality written code?

Comment: I wont say that. I think the problem is more coming from the process the code has been made. I don't know how you processed, but I would have started by made scroll bars design and adjusted the body to make sure that everything will fit correctly in it no matter screen size. You will have always a better way to make it. But you have to think about basic setting of a page. So I think, here the wrong thing was you did not think enought of "what are the priority". So get a body that keep other elements corectly is one of the 1st priority, because after it is a mess

Comment: Ah i see thank you so much for explaining that, would you by any chance have some advice or a way to set the body right for the content?

Comment: Because you know how I wrapped all my website content in a container. Could that be somehow making a problem for the content alignment?

Comment: Here an example with a basic css I would have done: https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/zYBGeqW Hope it can help. Please validate answer